# Nginx silent HTTP 200 response when fastcgi_params is not included in location

Tags: nginx

I've the following strange situation with Nginx.

/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:

```
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ cat /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
user vagrant;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;

pid        /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    access_log             /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    include                /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type           application/octet-stream;
    log_format  main       '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                           '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                           '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
    sendfile               off;
    keepalive_timeout      65;
    fastcgi_read_timeout   900;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  fh.local;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        error_page  404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
        }

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
        }

        include fastcgi_params;
        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    }
}
```

/etc/nginx/conf.d/auth.conf:

```
location ~ ^/auth {
    alias /var/www/auth/public;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/auth_access.log main;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/auth_error.log debug;

    try_files $uri $uri/ /auth/index.php?$uri;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        # include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/auth/public/index.php;
    }
}
```

When `include fastcgi_params;` is there and uncommented, everything works fine. But if I comment it (relying on the fact, that everything is already included at the `server` directive level, nginx starts to behave stranglely. Every request gives out a completely empty page with an HTTP 200 status code. No attempt to reach PHP backend is made (I can see that setting php-fpm log level to debug). Error log is the following:

```
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ cat /var/log/nginx/auth_error.log 
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 http cl:-1 max:1048576
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 rewrite phase: 3
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 post rewrite phase: 4
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 generic phase: 5
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 generic phase: 6
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 generic phase: 7
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 generic phase: 8
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 access phase: 9
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 access phase: 10
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 post access phase: 11
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 try files phase: 12
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 http script copy: "/var/www/auth/public"
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 http script var: "/auth/login"
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 trying to use file: "/auth/login" "/var/www/auth/public/auth/login"
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 http script var: "/auth/login"
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 trying to use dir: "/auth/login" "/var/www/auth/public/auth/login"
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 http script copy: "/auth/index.php?"
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 http script var: "/auth/login"
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 trying to use file: "/auth/index.php?/auth/login" "/var/www/auth/public/auth/index.php?/auth/login"
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 internal redirect: "/auth/index.php?/auth/login"
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 http cl:-1 max:1048576
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 rewrite phase: 3
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 post rewrite phase: 4
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 generic phase: 5
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 generic phase: 6
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 generic phase: 7
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 generic phase: 8
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 access phase: 9
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 access phase: 10
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 post access phase: 11
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 try files phase: 12
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 http init upstream, client timer: 0
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 epoll add event: fd:3 op:3 ev:80002005
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 http script copy: "SCRIPT_FILENAME"
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 http script copy: "/var/www/auth/public/index.php"
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 fastcgi param: "SCRIPT_FILENAME: /var/www/auth/public/index.php"
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 fastcgi param: "HTTP_HOST: fh.local:8080"
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 fastcgi param: "HTTP_CONNECTION: keep-alive"
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 fastcgi param: "HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL: max-age=0"
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 fastcgi param: "HTTP_ACCEPT: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8"
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 fastcgi param: "HTTP_USER_AGENT: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2125.122 Safari/537.36"
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 fastcgi param: "HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING: gzip,deflate,sdch"
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 fastcgi param: "HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE: ru,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6"
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 fastcgi param: "HTTP_COOKIE: laravel_session=eyJpdiI6InNRUzhsSmZDQW5sRllrckFpRGdNcGc9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiYjlyaVNhXC9XWjA0K3dGcVRJb1NmM1Z1KzJTVzNZUnFMQlVmdXQ4cit3Y2RQWUU2VUZ6eVFvdm1RYmFOZm1ERXBHVituZUNVRzNObW1BcVZXVlNKQ3l3PT0iLCJtYWMiOiI1OWRiNDQ5ZTgyMGI1ZTMzZDUyNzY5N2Y4MDczZTA4MDZmYmQ5MTFlMWI2YWJmODcwMTBhNzhmMzY5ZGQ0NmZiIn0%3D"
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 http cleanup add: 00007FB646A51F68
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 get rr peer, try: 1
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 socket 17
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 epoll add connection: fd:17 ev:80002005
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 connect to 127.0.0.1:9000, fd:17 #5
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 http upstream connect: -2
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 posix_memalign: 00007FB646A760F0:128 @16
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 event timer add: 17: 60000:1417000764181
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 http finalize request: -4, "/auth/index.php?/auth/login" a:1, c:3
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 http request count:3 blk:0
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 http finalize request: -4, "/auth/index.php?/auth/login" a:1, c:2
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 http request count:2 blk:0
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 http run request: "/auth/index.php?/auth/login"
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 http upstream check client, write event:1, "/auth/index.php"
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 http upstream recv(): -1 (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 http upstream request: "/auth/index.php?/auth/login"
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 http upstream send request handler
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 http upstream send request
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 chain writer buf fl:0 s:792
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 chain writer in: 00007FB646A51FA0
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 writev: 792
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 chain writer out: 0000000000000000
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 event timer del: 17: 1417000764181
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 event timer add: 17: 900000:1417001604183
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 http upstream request: "/auth/index.php?/auth/login"
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 http upstream process header
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 malloc: 00007FB646A02270:4096
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 recv: fd:17 80 of 4096
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 http fastcgi record byte: 01
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 http fastcgi record byte: 06
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 http fastcgi record byte: 00
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 http fastcgi record byte: 01
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 http fastcgi record byte: 00
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 http fastcgi record byte: 35
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 http fastcgi record byte: 03
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 http fastcgi record byte: 00
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 http fastcgi record length: 53
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 http fastcgi parser: 0
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 http fastcgi header: "X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.19"
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 http fastcgi parser: 0
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 http fastcgi header: "Content-type: text/html"
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 http fastcgi parser: 1
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 http fastcgi header done
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 xslt filter header
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.6.2
Date: Wed, 26 Nov 2014 11:18:24 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.19

2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 write new buf t:1 f:0 00007FB646A0AF90, pos 00007FB646A0AF90, size: 180 file: 0, size: 0
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 http write filter: l:0 f:0 s:180
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 http cacheable: 0
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 http upstream process upstream
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 pipe read upstream: 1
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 pipe preread: 19
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 readv: 1:4016
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 pipe recv chain: 0
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 pipe buf free s:0 t:1 f:0 00007FB646A02270, pos 00007FB646A022AD, size: 19 file: 0, size: 0
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 pipe length: -1
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 http fastcgi record byte: 01
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 http fastcgi record byte: 03
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 http fastcgi record byte: 00
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 http fastcgi record byte: 01
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 http fastcgi record byte: 00
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 http fastcgi record byte: 08
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 http fastcgi record byte: 00
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 http fastcgi record byte: 00
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 http fastcgi record length: 8
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 http fastcgi sent end request
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 free: 00007FB646A02270
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 pipe write downstream: 1
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 pipe write downstream done
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 event timer: 17, old: 1417001604183, new: 1417001604185
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 http upstream exit: 0000000000000000
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 finalize http upstream request: 0
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 finalize http fastcgi request
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 free rr peer 1 0
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 close http upstream connection: 17
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 free: 00007FB646A760F0, unused: 48
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 event timer del: 17: 1417001604183
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 reusable connection: 0
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 http upstream temp fd: -1
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 http output filter "/auth/index.php?/auth/login"
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 http copy filter: "/auth/index.php?/auth/login"
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 image filter
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 xslt filter body
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 http postpone filter "/auth/index.php?/auth/login" 00007FFFB26BDD00
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 http chunk: 0
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 write old buf t:1 f:0 00007FB646A0AF90, pos 00007FB646A0AF90, size: 180 file: 0, size: 0
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 write new buf t:0 f:0 0000000000000000, pos 00007FB64541B4DA, size: 5 file: 0, size: 0
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 http write filter: l:1 f:0 s:185
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 http write filter limit 0
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 writev: 185
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 http write filter 0000000000000000
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 http copy filter: 0 "/auth/index.php?/auth/login"
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 http finalize request: 0, "/auth/index.php?/auth/login" a:1, c:1
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 set http keepalive handler
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 http close request
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 http log handler
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 posix_memalign: 00007FB646A02270:4096 @16
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 free: 0000000000000000
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 free: 00007FB646A50FC0, unused: 0
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 free: 00007FB646A0A2C0, unused: 24
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 free: 00007FB646A02270, unused: 3821
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 free: 00007FB6469FDE50
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 hc free: 0000000000000000 0
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 hc busy: 0000000000000000 0
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 tcp_nodelay
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 reusable connection: 1
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 event timer add: 3: 65000:1417000769185
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 post event 00007FB646AC5A70
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 delete posted event 00007FB646AC5A70
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 http keepalive handler
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 malloc: 00007FB6469FDE50:1024
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 recv: fd:3 -1 of 1024
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 recv() not ready (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 free: 00007FB6469FDE50
2014/11/26 14:19:29 [debug] 20763#0: *1 event timer del: 3: 1417000769185
2014/11/26 14:19:29 [debug] 20763#0: *1 http keepalive handler
2014/11/26 14:19:29 [debug] 20763#0: *1 close http connection: 3
2014/11/26 14:19:29 [debug] 20763#0: *1 reusable connection: 0
2014/11/26 14:19:29 [debug] 20763#0: *1 free: 0000000000000000
2014/11/26 14:19:29 [debug] 20763#0: *1 free: 00007FB646A76570, unused: 0
2014/11/26 14:19:29 [debug] 20763#0: *1 free: 00007FB646A91180, unused: 120
```

Can anyone explain, why this blank-page-problem appears?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm trying to figure out why the `include fastcgi_params;` is needed in the location scope as well

Comment: @hafichuk May be, but I don't remember ;) It was a long-long ago.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use relative path from your root.
If your root path is /var/www
than use /auth/public/index.php to set fastcgi_params

root path is the default path which is used by localhost.

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME /auth/public/index.php;
}
```

try this nginx setting.

Comment: Try for what? The question was about why I should do `include fastcgi_params;` at the location level to get all this working when I have this directive set at server level.

Answer (score 0):

From the debug log it is clear the the request is passed to your backend, and the response in question is from the backend:

```
...
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 connect to 127.0.0.1:9000, fd:17 #5
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 http upstream connect: -2
...
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 http upstream send request handler
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 http upstream send request
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 chain writer buf fl:0 s:792
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 chain writer in: 00007FB646A51FA0
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 writev: 792
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 chain writer out: 0000000000000000
...
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 recv: fd:17 80 of 4096
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 http fastcgi record byte: 01
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 http fastcgi record byte: 06
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 http fastcgi record byte: 00
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 http fastcgi record byte: 01
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 http fastcgi record byte: 00
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 http fastcgi record byte: 35
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 http fastcgi record byte: 03
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 http fastcgi record byte: 00
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 http fastcgi record length: 53
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 http fastcgi parser: 0
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 http fastcgi header: "X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.19"
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 http fastcgi parser: 0
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 http fastcgi header: "Content-type: text/html"
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 http fastcgi parser: 1
2014/11/26 14:18:24 [debug] 20763#0: *1 http fastcgi header done
...
```

That is, nginx connected to the PHP backend, sent the request, and PHP returned an empty answer. If you don't see the request in PHP logs, there is something wrong with PHP logs.

As for the empty answer itself - likely it's how PHP reacts to absence of required parameters. While it's not exactly the best behaviour possible, it's more or less understandable.

Comment: Request never reached PHP as I could see turning on debugging mode. But anyway, why doesn't `include fastcgi_params;` work in my case? It was declared on `server` level and should be inherited by `location`.